# Using xs:group inside xs:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to define my XSD but I'm having troubles with the  element.

Here is my XML :

```
<key>Lambda, People</key>
<dict>
<key>Cost Center</key>
<string>  186B Hello Street, Mangilao</string>
<key>Organisation Path</key>
<string>NOA/NOZ</string>
<key>Phone Number</key>
<string>+1340232103</string>
<key>Room Number</key>
<string>GUM Sales</string>
<key>VoIP</key>
<string></string>
<key>title</key>
<string>Lambda, People</string>
</dict>
```

Here is what I want to use for my XSD :

```
<!-- <key>title</key><string>...</string> -->
<xs:group name="key_string_title">
<xs:sequence>
    <!-- <key>title</key> -->
    <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" fixed="title"/>
    <!-- <string>...<string> -->
    <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>                
</xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<!-- <key>title</key><string>...</string> -->


<!-- <key><string> -->
<xs:group name="key_string">
<xs:sequence>
    <!-- <key>...</key> -->
    <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>
    <!-- <string>...<string> -->
    <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>                
</xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<!-- <key><string> -->


<!-- <key><dict> Staff -->
<xs:group name="key_dict_staff">
<xs:sequence>
    <!-- <key> -->
    <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>

    <!-- <dict> -->
    <xs:element name="dict">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>                
                <!-- <key>title</key><string>...</string> -->
                        <xs:group ref="key_string_title"/>

                <!-- <key><string> -->
                <xs:group ref="key_string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <!-- </dict> -->

</xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<!-- </key></dict> Staff -->
```

Unfortunately, I saw it's impossible to use a group element inside an all element. How can I do it right considering this ? Am I missing something in the approach ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're trying to say is that there must be exactly one "title" and it can be anywhere in the sequence. You certainly can't achieve that this way: you are violating lots of rules in XSD, such as the "element declarations consistent" rule which says that if two sibling elements have the same name then they must have the same type.

You could do it of course with an assertion in XSD 1.1. There might be some creative way of using uniqueness constraints in XSD 1.0, but if there is then I can't see it.

My approach would be to redesign the XML instance to something more sanitary. Remember that there's always the option of transforming before validation.